How to determine (the lag order of) MA from these plots?
I am using time series to analyze the price of a commodity. Characterizing is the fact that the price of the good is determined per hour, one day prior to the day of delivery. For now, I have regressed the price of the good on several control variables and two lags of itself; the 24th lag (to account for daily patterns) and the 168th lag (to account for weekly patterns) of price. Price has been tested for stationarity. I am considering including a moving average component, but I am not very familiar with it.
I have read about considering the ACF and PACF plots and the correlogram of the residuals to get an idea about the feasibility and potential order of MA. Furthermore, it was suggested to look at the correlation of the errors. Therefore, I have included screenshots in the following folder;
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12ypoDX092AamYdwXkkzODjnmebf0-1wg?usp=sharing
My question is, do you think that including an MA component would be beneficial? If so, what lag order do you deem appropriate? If this information is insufficient, what other statistics should I consider? And, after including the MA term, which criterion can help determine whether the model is better?
Thank you in advance!

What is your objective in time series modeling? Do you want to forecast?

pacf and acf plots "in general" can't help much with model choice.

@StephanKolassa Thank you for your reply! The purpose is not really forecasting, but rather analyzing the effect of renewable energy on energy prices. I guess the predictive power of the model does not necessarily has to be very large, it is more important to control for other factors to isolate the effect of energy production from renewable sources :)

@Math-fun Thanks for the reply and good to know! Would statistical testing be better? Or is there another alternative I'm overlooking?

You are welcome: you could use an information criterion for model selection.

If your interest lies mainly in isolating the effect of an explanatory variable like renewable energy, then you need to include this explanatory variable in your model in "some" way. Simple (S)ARIMA does not know that there is some such variable around, and will not model it.
The simplest approach would be a regression on some explanatory predictor, followed possibly by fitting an ARIMA model to residuals... but if you are not interested in forecasting, this second ARIMA model is really not helpful, because the regression which enlightens you about the effect of the predictor is already done by the time you model the residuals.
For the entire process, it probably makes more sense to use an established auto-ARIMA method, rather than trying to make sense of ACF/PACF plots yourself: Selecting ARIMA orders by ACF/PACF vs. by information criteria Note that most auto-ARIMA implementations will consume explanatory variables are fit a regression with ARIMA errors as above.
However, this is actually a rather crude way of going about this. There are more sophisticated methods that will also account for the fact that there are likely relationships in both directions between renewable energy production, demand and prices, and energy prices. You would use econometric methods here, such as Vector Autoregression. Unfortunately, I can't say much about these... it might make sense to dig into an econometrics textbook.
